# update a .txt file with strings

Tags: java, file-io, arraylist, java.util.scanner, printwriter

Im trying to write a method that updates a .txt file with a new String.....what ive done is have it 1) read all the strings from the previously made txt file 
2)puts them into an arraylist
3) writes a new string to the arraylist 
4) then writes the toString() objects of that arraylist to a new file

it only writes the newest string to the file and none of the others even if i edit the file with multiple lines

here is what i have:

```
public static void updateNames(String newName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        name = new File("names.txt");
        infile = new Scanner(name);
        ArrayList<String> nameslist = new ArrayList<>();
        while(infile.hasNext()) {
            nameslist.add(infile.nextLine());
        }
        infile.close();
        nameslist.add(newName);
        names = new PrintWriter("names.txt");
        for(int i=0;i<nameslist.size();i++) {
            names.println(nameslist.get(i).toString());
        }
        names.close();
        System.out.println("else");
    }
```

just to be as clear as i can {name, names, and infile} are all declared as static void at the beginning of the class

thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `infile.hasNextLine()` instead of `infile.hasNext()`

change

```
   while(infile.hasNext())
```

to

```
  while(infile.hasNextLine())
```

and small correction

change

```
 names.println(nameslist.get(i).toString());
```

to

```
 names.println(nameslist.get(i)); //nameslist holds String objects no need to convert to String again.
```

if not solved the issue add countline variable and make sure how many lines you read from the file.

```
 int countline;
 while(infile.hasNext()) {
     nameslist.add(infile.nextLine());
     countline++;        
 }     
 System.out.println("Number of line: "+ countline);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, this seemed to work better for me. Soryy for the delayed reply ive just been on vaca for the holidays

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try this :

```
public static void updateNames(String newName) throws FileNotFoundException   {
    try {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("outfilename", true)));
        out.println(newName);
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
}
```

It will append `newName` at the end of the file text.

Comment: i tried this approach but it would still only write the last name to the file. I might not have been doing something right while using it but thanks anyways for the response....much appreciated